Render Razor View(.cshtml) to String Minimal Api
I am currently working on a minimal API project. API needs to have a send e-mail functionality using Razor View template in the body for the styling purposes. I have done some research but unfortunaly I cannot find a way do this with Minimal API since it doesn't have ControllerContext(not certain).
I have found the following topic on stack overflow
How to render an ASP.NET MVC view as a string?
Anwers in this topic contains the answer I need but the issue is Mimimal API does not have ViewContext or ViewData because it doesnt have controller function instead program.cs is used.
I have got the following code which successfully sends the email but cannot apply the design in to the e-mail body
public bool SendRequestDenied(string systemName)
{
  
    try
    {
        EmailRequestModel request = new EmailRequestModel();

        string Errormessage = string.Empty;

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        message.From = new MailAddress(_eMailFrom);
        message.Subject = systemName;
        message.Body = "This is where view needs to converted to string";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        List<string> emailRequests = GetListOfEmails();

        foreach (string emailList in emailRequests)
        {
            message.To.Add(emailList); 
        }

        //message.To.Add(request.EmailAddress[0]);

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(_mailServer);
        smtpClient.Send(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you mean something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-components-outside-of-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-9.0

@SynerCoder yes this looks like what I need but do you this can be applied in to a Minimal Api solution ?

I see no reason why not, just reference the packages needed
